# Interior, closure and boundary of subset in $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: general-topology

I have the subset $\left[0,1\right] \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$.

Am I right in thinking that this set is open and not closed in the space given?

Also, how do I go about finding the interior, closure and boundary?

Answer (score 2):

The sets $(0,1)\cap \Bbb{R}\backslash \Bbb{Q}$ and $[0,1] \cap \Bbb{R}\backslash \Bbb{Q}$ are respectively open and closed in $\Bbb{R}\backslash \Bbb{Q}$ by definition of the subspace topology. But they are both equal to $[0,1] \backslash \Bbb{Q}$. So $[0,1] \backslash \Bbb{Q}$ is both open and closed in $\Bbb{R}\backslash \Bbb{Q}$. Therefore, it is it's own interior and closure.

Answer (score 2):

You are partially correct in your thinking: your set is open, but, it is also closed.

Since $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q} = (0,1) \setminus \mathbb{Q} = (0,1) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$, and since the intersection of an open set with a subset is open in the subset topology, your set is closed in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

On the other hand, the complement 
$$(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \setminus ([0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}) = ((-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})
$$
is open for the same reason as above, and hence $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

For the remaining questions in your question, let us know your further thoughts, if it does not already make sense to you.